# ClawsMail 4.1; how to change default directories?

Tags: configuration, claws-mail

Currently, my mail boxes are scattered in multiple directories across my home directory.

I want to place all mail boxes under 1 directory: /home/Claws .

Can this be done, and how to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `/home/Claws` is not a standard location for mail. The client is usually run by users, so their accounts will be stored in their home dirs, eg. `/home/me1/.claws-mail`.

I assume for some mysterious reason your accounts are misconfigured and stored in various locations under your home address similar to `/home/me1`. You need to standardise this then.

If this is not available through the standard settings - and it may not be - take a look at the advanced settings app. It's called [Clawsker](https://www.claws-mail.org/clawsker.php) and it's ready for install in the standard repository on Debian. If that also doesn't help, you'll have to tweak the text configs.

Comment: Thanks for note. No, not misconfigured. Your note confirms my results to date.  I see nothing in the config files to suggest the directories can be altered: in fact, I see no directories. The question is whether Clawsmail can be configured by the user to place mailboxes into folders selected by the user.  To date, this seems impossible.  -regards

Comment: What structure do you want? All the Claws stuff should be by default in the `.claws-mail` dir under `$HOME` as described at https://claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Installation_and_Configuration#What_environment_variables_have_effect_on_Claws_Mail.3F. Accounts are configured in `accountrc` and the caches are in the same location by default. See https://claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Installation_and_Configuration#What_configuration_files_are_there.2C_and_what_are_they_used_for.3F

Comment: Thanks for note.  

When I, user rob, add a mailbox, named "newmail", Clawsmail defaults to a prefix '#mh'. The mails received on 'newmail' will be stored in the directory /home/newmail.

In /.claws-mail.account.rc , two lines are created ...
inbox=#mh/newmail@xxx.com/inbox
local_inbox=#mh/newmail@xxx.com/inbox

Question: what is the '#mh' ? I have no directories named '#mh' on my hard drive.

I want to place the 'newmail' as a subdirectory of 'Claws', like so... /home/Claws/newmail. 

How to do? Thanks.

Comment: ps. I know not how to format comments. This website removes all line 'cr'.